# Jquery .each() If statement not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css

Im trying to create a simple system which will position boxes in a grid system using jQuery.

**Current Progress**

I have created the grid positioning system which positions them side by side.

```
            var XPosition = 0;
            var YPosition = 0;

            $(".boxes").each(function() {
                $(this).css("left", XPosition);
                $(this).css("top", YPosition);
                $(this).css("height", $(".boxes").width());

                if (XPosition += $(this).width() < $("#gridCon").width()) {
                    XPosition += $(".boxes").width()-1;
                    console.log($("#gridCon").width());
                    console.log(XPosition);
                } else {
                    console.log(YPosition);
                    XPosition = 0;
                    YPosition += $(".boxes").height();
                }
```

**The Problem**

The grid goes beyond the screen width which is not desired. I tired to create an if statement which is aimed at reseting the left position and put it on a new row. However the if statement doesn't seem to be running correctly as I don't seem to be able to get the else statement

**JSFiddle -** https://jsfiddle.net/wLoqx4mj/

Comment: You are incrementing the Xposition twice

Comment: Ohh yeah I'm adding it in the IF statement as well, cheers for the spot

Comment: Also note that `$(".boxes").width()` will always return value of first one...you want the instance within loop

Comment: @charlietfl they all have the same width so shouldn't be an issue but thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess you need extra pair of parentheses on first line `if-condition`:

```
 if ((XPosition += $(this).width()) < $("#gridCon").width()) {
                    XPosition += $(".boxes").width()-1;
                    console.log($("#gridCon").width());
                    console.log(XPosition);
                } else {
                    console.log(YPosition);
                    XPosition = 0;
                    YPosition += $(".boxes").height();
                }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wLoqx4mj/3/)

Comment: Of Course, I'm so dumb :) Thank you, do you know why its add it twice now?

Comment: I got it sorry, I was adding it in my if with += instead I should just use +. Cheers